# <disconnected>DalvikVM[localhost:8615] How can I fix this error?

Tags: android, eclipse, debugging, stack-trace

When I try to run my android app, it first shows the MainActivity with a button. The button is supposed to start a service and then display another activity depending on the result of the service. But when I click the button, the app shuts down. I tried to debug it and I got this error stack trace: DalvikVM[localhost:8615].
What should I do?
Here's my MainActivity:

```
    public class MainActivity extends Activity implements OnClickListener {


@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    Button buttonStart = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button1);
    buttonStart.setOnClickListener(this);       
  }



public void onClick(View src) {     
    Toast.makeText(this, "OnClick", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    Intent serviceIntent = new Intent(src.getContext(), ForewarningService.class);  
    startService(serviceIntent);                      
    }
}
```

And here's my service:

```
    public class ForewarningService extends  Service {
private static final String TAG = "MyService";


@Override
public IBinder onBind(Intent intent) {
    return null;
}



public void onCreate() {

    Log.d(TAG, "onCreate");


}

public void onStart(Intent intent, int startid) {


    Log.d(TAG, "onStart");
    try{
    ForewarningAnalysisMod.runForewarning();


    }catch(Exception e)
    {
        e.printStackTrace();
        Toast.makeText(this, "Exception e", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }


}


public void onDestroy1() {

    Log.d(TAG, "onDestroy1");


    Intent attackIntent = new Intent(this, Result1Activity.class);
     attackIntent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
     this.startActivity(attackIntent);
}

public void onDestroy2() {
    Log.d(TAG, "onDestroy2");
     Intent noneventIntent = new Intent(this, Result2Activity.class);
     noneventIntent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
     this.startActivity(noneventIntent);
}
}
```

EDIT: I ran the app again not in debug mode and my logcat said this:

```
07-09 11:28:05.166: D/MyService(1606): onCreate
07-09 11:28:05.166: D/MyService(1606): onStart
07-09 11:28:05.196: W/System.err(1606): java.io.FileNotFoundException: /C:/ORNL-EEG/forewarn-COMPARATIVE-01/b12n49716w29s3d7l56m77gT-dmanalysis.csv (No such file or directory)
07-09 11:28:05.206: W/System.err(1606):     at org.apache.harmony.luni.platform.OSFileSystem.openImpl(Native Method)
07-09 11:28:05.206: W/System.err(1606):     at org.apache.harmony.luni.platform.OSFileSystem.open(OSFileSystem.java:152)
07-09 11:28:05.206: W/System.err(1606):     at java.io.FileOutputStream.<init>(FileOutputStream.java:97)
07-09 11:28:05.206: W/System.err(1606):     at java.io.FileOutputStream.<init>(FileOutputStream.java:69)
07-09 11:28:05.206: W/System.err(1606):     at java.io.FileWriter.<init>(FileWriter.java:80)
07-09 11:28:05.206: W/System.err(1606):     at edu.app.forewarn.model.LogWriter.<init>(LogWriter.java:17)
07-09 11:28:05.206: W/System.err(1606):     at edu.app.forewarn.ui.ForewarningAnalysisMod.runAnalysis(ForewarningAnalysisMod.java:136)
07-09 11:28:05.206: W/System.err(1606):     at edu.app.forewarn.ui.ForewarningAnalysisMod.runForewarning(ForewarningAnalysisMod.java:92)
07-09 11:28:05.206: W/System.err(1606):     at com.orhs.forewarningapp.ForewarningService.onStart(ForewarningService.java:40)
07-09 11:28:05.206: W/System.err(1606):     at android.app.Service.onStartCommand(Service.java:420)
07-09 11:28:05.216: W/System.err(1606):     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleServiceArgs(ActivityThread.java:3053)
07-09 11:28:05.216: W/System.err(1606):     at android.app.ActivityThread.access$3600(ActivityThread.java:125)
07-09 11:28:05.216: W/System.err(1606):     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:2096)
07-09 11:28:05.216: W/System.err(1606):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
07-09 11:28:05.216: W/System.err(1606):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:123)
07-09 11:28:05.216: W/System.err(1606):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4627)
07-09 11:28:05.216: W/System.err(1606):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
07-09 11:28:05.216: W/System.err(1606):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:521)
07-09 11:28:05.216: W/System.err(1606):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:868)
07-09 11:28:05.216: W/System.err(1606):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:626)
07-09 11:28:05.216: W/System.err(1606):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
07-09 11:28:05.226: I/AndroidRuntime(1606): AndroidRuntime onExit calling exit(-1)
```

And the folder says "it doesn't exist" actually does, I checked, so I don't know why I'm getting all of these errors.

Comment: Can you post the complete stack trace?

Comment: Can you also elaborate on what is going on inside of your service. We have no idea what ForwarningAnaylsisMod.runForewarning() is doing.

Comment: I was in debugging mode and that's all it said when it stopped.